# Prevent Spiner.setOnItemSelectedListener to change selection

Tags: android, spinner

I am developing a VIP future in my application. When user clicks on a vip option from spinner I want to show him a popup rather than changing spinner selection.

How would you solve it?

*Note that I don't want to disable setOnItemSelectedListener, just for vip options.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Save your current selected position/item in a variable.
2. In your OnItemSelectedListener:

   a. if a VIP item is selected show your popup and reset your selection to saved position.

   b. else proceed normally.